# How to get logs of app from android without using android studio?

Tags: android

I have given App to my friend but its not working.I want to know the issue  so that I want log file of my App.Is there anyway to get logs from android without using android studio or any debugger tool.I want only log file to get solve issue.So What is the way to get log file from android device.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add google firebase in your app.

Comment: Integrate fabric in your application.

Comment: Try this : adb logcat -d -v time > logfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

> Use Fabric io Crashlytics for reports and errors

for more information  visit: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

You can use [firebase log events.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to add Firebase inside your app, With the help of Firebase Crashing Report, you can check all the crashes from your app

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Log events. Please check the link below:
[Firebase Log events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events)

Answer (score 0):

I have same question about you that's why I built the Clerk.

https://github.com/Jintin/Clerk

Clerk is an Android app can install on your device which collect log information by broadcast receiver.

By using this, you can easily delegate you log to it. And you can view the result by open the app. Leverage on LiveData it's realtime and in same device without send the log online.

Let me know if you have any other input. Thanks.